# Rails conditional redirect after delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to redirect after a delete depending on where the user came from.

This is the current code in the event controller:

```
def destroy
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @event.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to events_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

I changed it to this (thanks MrYoshiji):

```
format.html { redirect_to :back }
```

That works if the user was deleting from all pages except the Event show page.  Because you then get an error trying to show a record you just deleted.

So, I'm trying to use a params to tell the destroy code where to redirect to.

I'm trying this:

```
def destroy
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @event.destroy
  @return_url

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @return_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

But, I don't know how to pass the @return_url as a param in the link_to on a  show page.

```
    <%= link_to 'Delete', @event, params(@return_url => "some url"), confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete, :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

How would I pass the url as a param?

Thanks!!

UPDATE1

I changed the Event controller to this:

```
 def destroy
   @expense = Expense.find(params[:id])
   redirect_url = (request.referer.include?("#{@event.id}/show") ? events_url : :back)
   @expense.destroy

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to redirect_url }
     format.json { head :ok }
   end
 end
```

This redirects back to the correct page the "Delete Event" button is on - except when I click that button on the show page for the Event.

The redirect wants to show the deleted record.

UDPATE2

OK this worked for my app:

```
    redirect_url = (request.referer.include?("/events/#{@event.id}") ? events_url : :back)
```

THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP !!

Comment: `return_url = (request.referer.include?('show') ? <url_helper_to_index_path> : :back)` and then `redirect_to return_url`

Comment: @MrYoshiji almost there, there, but this gets any `show` URL, don't it?

Comment: With nested routes you don't have the `show` keyword, example with one of my deep nested routes: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/settings/organisations/1/clinics/1/edit` But you are right, it should be `include?("#{@current_resource.id}/show")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I commented, you could do the following:

```
def destroy
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @event.destroy
  redirect_url = (request.referer.include?("#{@event.id}/show") ? events_url : :back)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to redirect_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

(I am not sure you can access to `@event.id` right after you deleted it, if not, destroy it after we set the `redirect_url`

Comment: Thanks for the help !! See my UPDATE1 in the question.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the redirect_url statement is doing.  Is it testing to see if the last page was the event/show page? The show page has this url `http://localhost:5000/events/29`

Comment: Should it be something like ("events/#{@event.id}")

Comment: Too see what's going on, is there a way to do an alert inside the destroy code?  Something like      `alert request.referer.txt` or `alert request.referer.val()`

Comment: This worked `(request.referer.include?("/events/#{@event.id}")`

Answer (score 0):

In your view:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', event_path(@event, url), confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete, :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

Here I'm passing the `url` variable as a parameter to the controller.

In controller:

```
...
@return_url = params[:url]
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is bad to pass raw URL's from the view.

Comment: incrementing drhenner comment, it can be used to explore vulnerabilities

Comment: Thanks, I didn't now. I just answered: "But, I don't know how to pass the @return_url as a param in the link_to on a show page."

Comment: Incrementing the comments here, we just have to add `?url=facebook.com` and we would be redirect to ...... facebook.com!

Comment: I guess my original idea of using a parameter in the URL is not a good one. Thanks for the info.